# how to find accuracy while dealing with pickle files in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

This is my code. Here I am trying to predict the number of faults using gradient boosting regressor.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
# GradientBoostingRegressor
regr3 = GradientBoostingRegressor(random_state=0)
regr3.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())    

pkl_filename = "GradientBoostingRegressor.pkl"
    with open(pkl_filename, 'wb') as file:
        pickle.dump(regr3, file)

    # Load from file
    with open(pkl_filename, 'rb') as file:
        pickle_model = pickle.load(file)

    score = pickle_model.score(X_test, y_test)
    print("Test score: {0:.2f} %".format(100 * score))
    Ypredict = pickle_model.predict(X_test)
    print(Ypredict)
    a= Ypredict.reshape(-1,1)
    accuracy_score= pickle_model.score(a, y_test)
    print(accuracy_score)
```

And on executing the score is easily calculated (99.69%). But the accuracy has not calculated. I also have another doubt-- can we select a model with highest test_score as the best model. or should I find accuracy and find the one with the highest accuracy to get the model?
 The error encountered is ----"Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 52 and input n_features is 1"

Comment: Your code is not an [mre] - we cannot execute it and see the error for ourself. Please [edit] and give a full [mre] to work with. What does a print of the shape of `a` and `y_test` give you? It seems `y_test` is not correct.

Comment: thank you for your response sir . i will edit it as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

accuracy_score is for check the performance of classification models.Since you are using regression model,you should use r2 score,mse or rmse scores.for more info check the all [model evaluation functions](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) here.

for example

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
r2_score(a, y_test)
```

Comment: I have done the same sir. But got error..  ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of continuous and multiclass targets

Comment: @devikasathyan accuracy_score is use for basically classification models.you are using regression model.you should check your model performance using r2 ,mse or rmse.check this link https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html

Comment: Thank you sir... i solved it ... thank you for your time sir